# Validate RadioButtonList value with jQuery before submit

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I am not good at jquery and I am trying to prevent .net form from submitting if user selects Yes(1) in the RadioButtonList pathway. Below is my code and I have no clue why it doesn't work.
The form name turns to aspnetform when I run the .net application and the radPathway RadioButtonList becomes #ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$radPathway:

```
<script>
    $('#aspnetForm').submit(function () {
        if ($('#ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$radPathway').val() === "1") {
            alert('Stop!');
            return false;
        }
    });
</script>
```

.aspx code:

```
<p>
    <asp:Label ID="Label23" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" 
        Text="Pathway member?"></asp:Label>
    &nbsp;
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="radPathway" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="50px">
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">Yes</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="0">No</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>

    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator17" runat="server" 
                ControlToValidate="radPathway" ErrorMessage="Please select your pathway status" ForeColor="red">
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

    <asp:Label ID="lblpathway" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Text="Label" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. This is how you should determine the value of the checked item. Replace "test" with the name element on both list items you see when you view the source of your page.

```
function getCheckedRadio() {
  var radioButtons = document.getElementsByName("test");
  for (var x = 0; x < radioButtons.length; x ++) {
    if (radioButtons[x].checked) {
      var selectedValue = radioButtons[x].value;
    }
  }
}

if (selectedValue == "1") {
    //rockmysocks
}
```